# Stream, return value of characters that didn't pass the filter

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I would like to count the characters that didn't pass the filter, and return this value too. How can i do that?

My exc:
Within class `LambdasStreamExercise`, implement method `dnaToWeight` in order to determine the molecular weight of a DNA sequence string from its nucleotides. Implement these individual steps in your stream:

- Start with `DNA.chars()` to initiate a Stream. This will be one of integers.
- Filter out those that do not represent regular DNA (Challenge: and count them)
- Convert to a stream of Character objects from the given DNA sequence
- Convert the Characters into Nucleotide objects
- Convert the Nucleotide objects to their weights
- Sum the weights and return the result (And report the number of rejected nucleotides)

```
 public static double dnaToWeight(String DNA) {
        double dnaWeightTotal = DNA.chars()
                .filter(c -> c == 'A' || c == 'T' || c == 'G' || c == 'C')
                .mapToObj(c -> new Nucleotide((char) c))
                .mapToDouble(c -> (double) c.getWeight())
                .sum();
        return dnaWeightTotal;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use the [`partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.stream.Collector)) collector? That takes a predicate and a mapping function and gives you a `Map<Boolean, T>` that groups your objects into "matching" and "non-matching".

Comment: *count the characters that didn't pass the filter* - if you want to it in the same stream pipeline with all the steps of your assignment, then it's **not doable** without dirty tricks like stateful `filter` that violate the guidelines listed in the documentation. Conditional logic and streams don't play well together.

Comment: Convert the Nucleotide objects to their weights, is the weight determined by the amount of times the specific char/nucleotide occurred in the DNA?

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to do the job would be to make an intermediate list:

```
public static double dnaToWeight(String DNA) {
    List<Double> weights = DNA.chars()
            .filter(c -> c == 'A' || c == 'T' || c == 'G' || c == 'C')
            .mapToObj(c -> new Nucleotide((char) c).getWeight())
            .toList();
    int countNonRegular = DNA.length() - weights.size(); // to be used elsewhere
    return weights.stream().reduce(Double::sum).orElse(0.0);
}
```

Note: The method `toList` is new in Java 16.

Comment: [Stream.toList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()) is introduced in Java 16